# Swift: ObjectiveC RunTime unrecognized copyWithZone error for value types

Tags: ios, swift, runtime, copywithzone

I am looking to migrate some code from Swift -> Objective C starting with unit tests.

I am having issues with mocking functions that passes value types:

```
let initWithTitleBlock : @objc_block (String, String) -> AlertViewMock! = { (title : String, message : String) -> (AlertViewMock!) in
    alert = AlertViewMock(title: title, message: message)
    return alert
}
let initWithTitleImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(unsafeBitCast(initWithTitleBlock, AnyObject.self))
let initWithTitleMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(AlertView.self, Selector("initWithTitle:message:"))
method_setImplementation(initWithTitleMethod, initWithTitleImp)
```

But I end up getting the following error at runtime:

> -[AlertView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fef006e4cb0

However, if I change the type getting passed into the block as `AnyObject` or some other reference type like `NSURL`, I am able to successfully run the new block (except I cannot convert the object back into a string):

```
let initWithTitleBlock : @objc_block (AnyObject, AnyObject) -> AlertViewMock! = { (title : AnyObject, message : AnyObject) -> (AlertViewMock!) in ...
```

I did not mark `AlertViewMock` as `copy`. May anyone help explain what's going on? If I pass in `NSInteger`, I get the same exception:

```
let initWithTitleBlock : @objc_block (NSInteger, NSInteger) -> AlertViewMock! = { (title : NSInteger, message : NSInteger) -> (AlertViewMock!) in ...
```

Comment: Figured it out. The first argument is actually the class that is being swizzled which is AlertViewMock. By binding it to String, it indirectly calls copyWithZone. I updated the function to:
   
    let initWithTitleBlock : @objc_block (AnyObject, String, String) -> AlertViewMock! = { (title : String, message : String) -> (AlertViewMock!) in
        alert = AlertViewMock(alertView: AnyObject, title: title, message: message)
        return alert
    }